# How to log php error in a separate file?

Tags: php, apache-http-server, error-logging

I just did an upgrade of my server to Fedora 17 and merged some configuration files containing `.rpmnew` into the existing ones. I have been successfully logging my php errors in a separate log file by keeping the following in `php.ini`:

```
log_errors = On
error_log = /var/log/php-errors.log
```

I am not sure why the errors are being logged to `/var/log/httpd/error_log` after the upgrade despite keeping the settings above.

Also,

```
$ ls -l /var/log/php-errors.log
-rwxrwxr--. 1 apache myself 232 Dec 13 16:49 /var/log/php-errors.log
```

shows that apache did own the php error log file.

What could be causing PHP errors to be logged into apache error log file?

Comment: @DaveRandom, from `phpinfo()`, it shows the loaded config file to be /etc/php.ini, which is correct.

Comment: Have you tried setting the permissions on `/var/log/php-errors.log` to 666, in case the user/groups are not set up how you think they are?

Comment: @DaveRandom, thanks for the suggestion. I tried, and it still send the error to apache error log. Even disabling SELinux does not help a bit :(

Answer (score 0):

I think that here it's just the generic Apache errors that are seen in `/var/log/httpd/error_log`.

I would insert a call to `error_log('test');` into some PHP logic that is known to get interpreted when some specific page is refreshed, and if that's not seen in `/var/log/php-errors.log` then I'd suspect that the versions upgraded to have some kind of a different config or permissions scheme that made the old config stop working.

I'd recommend going through the 'Error handling and logging' section in `/etc/php/php.ini`, and checking for proper values for other directives.  The directive `error_reporting` should be set to `E_ALL` or `E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`.  The directive `log_errors` should be `On`.

If just a filename (but no path) is specified for `error_log`, then the file will appear in the same directory as the PHP script that calls `error_log(...)`.

I'd also recommend specifying `/tmp/php_error_log` for `error_log`, refreshing the page, and then `ls /tmp` to see if the file is there.

If the file is not there, login as root, and do a search for the file name across the whole file system so see where it ended up.

Generally, the proper config to get PHP error log working in a particular directory changes across different versions of Apache, PHP, and various distros.

I can say that on Arch Linux with Apache 2.4, PHP 5.5.11 and systemd version 212-1 the config above will make the PHP error log end up somewhere similar to `/tmp/systemd-private-65d4c3e3cc534155bcf3ec708c2362f6-httpd.service-h8MSsD/tmp/php_error_log`.

Comment: Nope, those are PHP errors, not general errors. And I did give it a full path instead of a relative path. And it used to work two years ago.